# How does TeamExtreme MC launcher bypass auth?

Tags: java, executable-jar, minecraft, launch, launcher

I am  developing a custom game launcher and as I was looking on how to launch minecraft 1.7.4 it seemed to me that the *.jar cannot be launched without setting an authentication process to the mojang site. However, TeamExtreme minecraft launcher bypasses this. How?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it just sends in false data, or empty data. This should allow minecraft to launch in offline mode, meaning that it lets you join but you are not logged in, so that you cannot play on servers.

I am not entirely sure, however, this should send you on the right track.

Comment: You actually CAN play multiplayer, moreover the jar simply needs valid access token to start

Comment: Well, right. That was just in the context of offline mode.

Comment: Wait, it DOES need a valid access token? It doesnt just launch in offline mode?

Comment: To apply skin I think yes, and the skin is there when using team extreme mc launcher

Comment: No, the skins server works as long as a username is applied. Emails maybe. I havent tested.

Comment: But username isn't applied in offline mode. To apply username acc token is needed

Comment: I happened to look into it. There's a run parameter "username" and "authToken".